# Rxjs: Object as Observable with inner observables as values

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service which returns an object 'Recipe' as an observable. The Recipe object has an owner list with an Id.

My service takes these ids and returns an array of observables with the actual detail of the owner. In my template I can subscribe to the main Recipe observable with the async flag, then use async flag on the owner inner observable value.

Example

Base Object

```
Recipe = {
  name: Cake,
  price: £3.99,
  type: Sweet,
  owner: 1293jhd8sdhs,
  book: ju3923872u2,
  ingredients: [
    9j3hj383j398w,
    jmfjd8672372i,
    82378u2ndfmff,
 ]
}
```

Service:

```
    return this.firestoreSvc.docAsObs(`recipes/${id}).pipe(
      map(recipeDetails => {
          recipeDetails['userDetails'] = this.firestoreSvc.docAsObs(`users/${recipeDetails.owner})
          recipeDetails['bookDetails'] = this.firestoreSvc.docAsObs(`books/${recipeDetails.book})
          recipeDetails['ingredientDetails'] = recipeDetails.ingredients.map(x => this.firestoreSvc.docAsObs('ingredients/${x}')
          recipeDetails['ingredientDetails'] = combineLatest(recipeDetails['ingredientDetails']
          return recipeDetails
    )
```

The firestoreSvc.docAsObs just returns an Observable with the path with the snapshotChanges for the id (using AngularFire2)

Object returned from service

```
Recipe = {
  name: Cake,
  price: £3.99,
  type: Sweet,
  owner: 1293jhd8sdhs,
  userDetails : Observable,
  bookDetails: Observable,
  ingredientDetails: Observable[],
}
```

Rightly or wrongly this works fine. In my template I handle (Food | async) and (Food.userDetails | async) to display the values

However now I need to access the userDetails value in my components. Rather than multiple subscribes, I was sure there could be an easier way with the all powerful rxjs but I cannot get it to work.

I have searched and tried flatMap to flatten the observables, plus mergeMap, forkJoin and concatAll() but either nothing gets returned or I don't return a stream.

Just wondering if anyone can help. I like have a firestoreSvc to return my the observables, hopefully using this isn't hindering me

Thanks

Lee

Comment: You are speaking of several observables, but I only see the recipe and userDetails observable. flatten is for arrays. Do you have an array anywhere? Did you try combineLatest?

Comment: I didn't include all to simply, thinking premise was the same, perhaps wrong of me. I do use combineLatest on my array of observables, again using | async in template, I was just hoping I could use an operator in either service or component to return all the observables at once

Comment: Have you tried `async as` in your template?

Comment: yes async as works in my template, but I need the 'xDetails' data in my component. I could not use the async flag and do `recipeDetails['bookDetails'].subscribe(x => this.bookDetails = x)`  and repeat for users/ingredients but was hoping an operator could handle this in a single operation

Comment: Why don't you have an observable by mapping the `Recipe.userDetails` and use that observable to be used in the template via `async` pipe. While mapping you can set a variable of the component which will hold the value of `userDetails`. Once `async` will unwrap the value from the observable, the component variable will als be set. This variable you can use in your component as per your logic.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I unwrap in template for instance `*ngIf="userDetails | async as userDetail"` then `userDetail` from the template won't be available in the component?